# cannot catch strophe.js timeout

Tags: javascript, error-handling, strophe

How can i catch an Timed out error in strophe? Ive googled and tried to read through the sourcecode, but it doesnt really mention timeouts other than request timeouts.

It throws me this error message:

```
OPTIONS http://example.com:7070/http-bind/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

It doesn't kill the script as this will loop 5-6 times until it stops. Console reads it as an error, so i dont know how to catch it.

```
connection.Status.ERROR does not catch timeouts
```

Comment: have you tried Status.CONNFAIL or Status.DISCONNECTED?

Comment: my listeners were actually dead! I will try this as soon as i can. meaning, next time the server dies =) 
You are probably 100% right. Thanks!